# Inserir número de linha no SQL Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Olá!

Estou tentando ver o número de linhas na lateral da consulta do meu SQL Manager, mas não consigo achar onde colocar, alguém poderia me ajudar?
Estou recebendo um erro na minha query e ele informa a linha, mas está difícil identificar sem.

Answer (score 5):

Dependendo da sua versão do SSMS o caminho é:

> Menu superior >> Ferramentas (Tools) >> Opções (Options) >> Editor de
>   Texto (Text Editor) >> Geral (General) >> Habilite a opção: Número da
>   Linha (Line Number) no quadro Display.

Ou:

> Menu superior >> Ferramentas (Tools) >> Opções (Options) >> Editor de
>   Texto (Text Editor) >> Transact-SQL >> Habilite a opção: Números de
>   Linha (Line Number) no quadro Configurações.

Comment: Deu certo a segunda opção, uso a versão 2017. Obrigado!